# What color can lightsabers be?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

I just saw the fan film *[Broken Allegiance](https://vimeo.com/1412286)* and the Force-sensitive bounty-hunter, Korbain Thor, wielded an ochre lightsaber (or at least that's what [the wiki entry](http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Broken_Allegiance) described it as).

I'm just wondering if ochre is a canon color for a lightsaber?

[image]

Comment: Which shade of ochre are you referring to? There are four options that I know of : Yellow ochre also called Gold ochre,
Red ochre, Purple ochre and Brown ochre

Comment: We [took the liberty](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11123/20774) of editing your question's title a bit so that it becomes obvious that its answer applies to any colour, not just ochre, since there were a few questions about the lightsaber colours, and yours has the most comprehensive answer.

Comment: Damn Gallifreyans, always messing with the time line.

Comment: Ultraviolet lightsabers are especially dangerous. Nobody ever sees those ones coming.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Disney Canon

Lightsaber blades are powered by the [Kyber Crystal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) it contains which gets its color from its being attuned to its owner. Most typically, they end up blue or green. Since the crystals were inherently attuned to the Light Side, [Sith/Dark Side users were forced to "bend" the will of the crystals, making them "bleed", creating the red color](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143240/5184). Currently, the only known colors are:

- Black (The Dark Saber)
- Blue (Obi-Wan's lightsaber)
- Green (Yoda's lightsaber)
- Purple (Mace Windu's lightsaber)
- Red (Darth Vader/Darth Maul's lightsabers)
- Silver (Tera Sinube's lightsaber)
- White (Ashoka Tano's lightsaber)
- Yellow (Jedi Temple Guards lightsabers)

Thus far, synthetic crystals have not appeared in the new canon. While [Pablo Hidalgo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo), has said that his tweets should not necessarily be treated as canon, he has noted that ["No, the synthetic crystal thing is Legends. Maul. Sidious. Vader. All those were kyber crystals."](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/678275796058771456)

So, in Disney Canon, there is no evidence that a lightsaber could be "ochre" specifically, but one of the "yellow" hues may come close.

### Legends

Lightsaber colors are determined by the crystals used to power the blade. In more modern times, synthetic crystals were created and used instead of mining natural crystals. This made blades of almost any color possible.

That said, here are the known colors of lightsaber blades as per [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber_crystal).

- Amber
- Aqua (Galen Marek's modified lightsaber)
- Azure (Nikkos Tyris's lightsaber)
- Black (White with black core)
- Blue (traditional Jedi lightsaber color)
- Blue, w/ black core
- Blue, Dark (such as Anakin Skywalker's lightsaber, Kenobi's Legacy)
- Blue, Icy (Permafrost crystal)
- Blue, Jade
- Bright Gold
- Bronze (Bnar's Sacrifice)
- Bronze w/ yellow core (Heart of the Guardian)
- Brown
- Carmine (Bane's Heart)
- Clear (Barab ore)
- Cobalt (One of Saesee Tiin's many lightsaber's)
- Crimson (such as Adi Gallia's lightsaber in 32 BBY)
- Cyan (such as Meetra Surik's lightsaber)
- Cyan w/ silvery glow (Mantle of the Force)
- Electric Blue
- Emerald (such as Jacen Solo's lightsaber before his ascension to Sith Lord)
- Gold (such as Qu Rahn's lightsaber)
- Gray
- Green
- Green, Dark
- Green, Jade
- Green, Light
- Green, Sage (Rahm Kota's lightsaber)
- Green w/ black core (Dahgee crystal)
- Indigo
- Lava (Lava crystal)
- Magenta (such as Mara Jade Skywalker's lightsaber)
- Orange (such as Kyle Katarn in 10 ABY or Freedon Nadd) 
  Pre Vizsla wielding his unique black-bladed Darksaber.
- Pearl White (Krayt dragon pearl, Wisdom crystal)
- Pewter(Raynar Thul's lightsaber)
- Pink (Lambent)
- Purple
- Red (Darth Andeddu's Crystal, generic Sith/Dark Jedi lightsaber)
- Red, w/ black core
- Red, Blood (Qixoni crystal)
- Red, Dark
- Red, Light
- Sapphire (Yarael Poof's lightsaber)
- Scarlet (Depa Billaba's lightsaber)
- Silver (Durindfire (crystal))
- Silvery-blue
- Silvery-green (Viridian crystal)
- Teal (Sunrider's Destiny)
- Transparent Blue (Pix's lightsaber)
- Violet (such as Anakin Solo, Kyp Durron, and Jaina Solo's lightsabers)
- Violet, Dark
- Violet, Light
- Viridian
- White
- Yellow (such as the new Impact Crystal, a Force Unleashed 2 Collectors Edition Exclusive, and Yun's lightsaber)
- Yellow, Dark
- Yellow, Light
- Yellow-White (Nelani Dinn's lightsaber)
- Yellowish-green (such as Ahsoka Tano's Shoto)
- Yellowish-orange
- Yellow w/ Black Core

As you can see, there is no "ochre" listed, but as Chetter pointed out, "ochre" can actually mean a few things. Without specifying a variant, "ochre" usually refers to a golden-yellow or a yellow-brown.

Ignoring synthetic crystals, there are two crystals which produce colors close to these shades:

[Velmorite](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Velmorite)

[image]

[Ulric's Redemption](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ulic%27s_Redemption)

[image]

To be fair, Ulric's Redemption is a little closer to brown than yellow.

Comment: ... so.. pretty much any color.

Comment: @Omegacron Pretty much, yes. The whole synthetic crystals thing really blew open the whole option set.

Comment: well, heck - +1 for variety.