# Has there ever been a black lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

Has anyone in the Star Wars books ever wielded a black lightsaber, one that expels black light making the surroundings darker?

Is there a reason he/she uses one?

Comment: Even Star Wars doesn't hate physics that much, no.

Comment: You could, I suppose, have a sabre that absorbed light. "Black light", as we currently use the term is just light that humans can't see (ultraviolet). Dark is just the absence of light so, short of magic, you can't emit or expel it. Same with cold - cold is just the absence of heat. You can emit heat, you can absorb heat but you can't emit cold.

Comment: Surely that would be a darksaber...

Comment: @Jeff - I think you overestimate Lucas's respect for reality, science, the immensity of space, and how time works.

Comment: The closest something can come to emitting "dark" would be a light saber that also exudes a dust or fog. A Smog Saber.

Comment: Also see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21310/397 for a full list of colors.

Comment: @Donald.McLean just by reading your comment, it occured to me that that actual Black Lightsaber (or Dark Saber as Sardathrion said) WOULD be very, VERY viable. I mean, it exists, but you can't see the blade. Heck, if I was some sort of assassin I'd love to have a blade that my opponents couldn't see me weild

Comment: A sabre that absorbed light would not be invisible, but would be harder to see - harder even than a physical black object which reflects very little light. Not invisible because there would be a noticeable "black zone".

Comment: Since the other question was earlier, and since it's accepted answer contains th complete list of colours, I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Oak - you couldn't see it to avoid cutting your arm off though.

Comment: We're clearly talking about distinct things, as when I meant a dark saber, I meant one that would only reflect ultraviolet colours of the light spectrum, which would actually be invisible. @Oldcat, that's true, but I actually thought about it as in : "I point it, I click on a button, the saber expands and the other guy doens't see the blade dicing him"

Comment: Nominating for re-opening because the linked question is not the same, although the accepted answer on it does answer this.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Voting to leave closed because "This question already has an answer here". (IIRC, there was a troll attempt when somebody posted dozens of "Can lightsabers be ochre?" "Can lightsabers be puce?" "Can lightsabers be sky-blue pink?" questions, and they all got shut down as dupes of the one with an all-encompassing answer.)

Answer (score 35):

There is the [Darksaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber_%28lightsaber%29), but it does not make the surroundings darker, the core of the blade was black, while the outer edges glowed white.

There are also some black lightsaber crystals in some video games, like *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed*, but they shine the same way as the darksaber.

[image: Starkiller wielding a black lightsaber.]

Comment: Oh. Well, that's interesting, too...

Comment: Oh, I didn't not know that they were one and the same. I will remove my answer.

Comment: it's just an optical illusion.  it's really a white lightsabre

Comment: They also use these in The Clone Wars

Answer (score -4):

The soulsaber, which was created using dark side magic. Being a nexus of dark side energy, its very presence would corrupt the atmosphere and those within it

Comment: Can you add some references?

Comment: References are required please! Have you seen the [help]?

Comment: never heard of that. And anyway, to call it "magic" is not in context for the Star Wars universe, nor is the "soul".

Comment: @Keen: Did I err in adding citations to Wookiepedia?

Comment: @SeanDuggan That edit was way too drastic.  You completely overhauled the answer, and that's not [what edits are for](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing).