# Why do the Sith use red-colored lightsabers, but the Jedi don't?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

As far as I have seen, the Jedi have different color lightsabers viz. blue, green...but, all the Sith have red-colored lightsabers. I don't have a heavy grip on Legends, so I can't declare it an universal rule, but look at this:
In the last episode of Season 4 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, Asajj Ventress gave her one of lightsabers to Obi-Wan Kenobi and said, "I want that back."
Then, Obi-Wan Kenobi replied, "Alright. That's not my color."

It means that Jedi don't use red-colored lightsabers. My question: Why? I don't think color has something to do with Force use or abuse. Anyone can pick their favorite colored crystal to create their lightsaber. What's the problem with red?

Anakin was using a blue-colored lightsaber that he lost in the battle with Obi-Wan. But, after becoming Vader, he started to use red-colored lightsaber. Why do the Sith use red-colored lightsabers?

Comment: There is an excellent TVTrope covering [Good Colours vs Evil Colours](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoodColorsEvilColors), specifically using Star Wars as an example! Excerpt: *where the hero is blue and the villain is red (as this probably results from the "good" American and "evil" British colors during the US War of Independence)*

Comment: This is a different question that was asked previously.

Comment: http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0207.html Ultimately, they don't do it, because if they did, it would be much more difficult for the audience to keep track of whom they're supposed to be rooting for.

Comment: While related, the questions aren't really the same - and there is a new canon answer that addresses this specifically.

Comment: Adi Gallia (Jedi Master and member of the Jedi Council) used a red lightsaber in a variety of Legends properties. http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20060128124528/starwars/images/thumb/4/4e/Raid_on_the_Jedi_Temple_%28Yinchorri_Uprising%292.JPG/640px-Raid_on_the_Jedi_Temple_%28Yinchorri_Uprising%292.JPG. Her Episode 1 figurine even had a red lightsaber http://thumbs4.picclick.com/d/l400/pict/131689901063_/NEW-1999-Hasbro-Star-Wars-Episode-I.jpg

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### They're actually red *because* the Sith use them.

This is addressed in the novel [Ahsoka](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_(novel)).

First the book explains that the Force can change the colors of the crystals used in the lightsabers, mentioning that the dark crystals (used by the Sith) end up "bleeding" until they are "the deepest red". The crystals used by the Sith are naturally colored crystals typically stolen from light-side users, which are then corrupted.

> Dark crystals were made, too, but not in that holy place. They were plundered from their rightful bearers and corrupted by the hands that stole them. Even rock could be changed by the power of the Force, bleeding alterations until their color was the deepest red. The balance was finely staged between the two, light and dark, and it took very little to upset it.

Ahsoka later explains this further when she shows off her new white sabers. She explains that she has restored them back to their original white after having been corrupted into their red coloration by the Dark Side.

> “I’ve never seen white ones before,” Bail mused.
>
> “They used to be red,” Ahsoka said. “When the creature had them, they were red. But I heard them before I ever saw him on Raada, and knew that they were meant for me.”
>
> “You changed their nature?” he asked.
>
> “I restored them,” Ahsoka replied. “I freed them. The red crystals were corrupted by the dark side when those who wielded them bent them to their will. They call it making the crystal bleed. That’s why the blade is red.”

Comment: Aw, I answered a similar question, about the color of lightsabers generally. I missed this one, though!

Comment: I remember seeing a youtube video explaining that they are white not because they were naturally white and got restored, but that they were a different color like blue/green and they got restored after bleeding. That is why nobody has seen white ones before.

Answer (score 36):

The primary reason for the Sith utilizing red lightsabers had to deal with their manufacture, using synthetic crystals which were initially red in color. Synthetic crystals were not normally used in lightsabers due to their unstable nature. However, a breakthrough in their development allowed the Sith users to augment the synthetic crystal with the Dark Side of the Force creating a more powerful lightsaber. Nowadays, it is possible to create lightsabers with any color blade using the same augmented dark-force modifications but it has become somewhat of a tradition among the Sith to use the red-colored light saber.

> - Though synthetic crystals were ordinarily unsuitable for use in lightsabers, the Sith discovered that they could create synth-crystals that were energized, magnetized, and modified with the power of the dark side of the Force in special furnaces, causing the crystal to glow in harmonic vibration.
> - **As a result of their artificial origins, synthetic crystals created more powerful lightsaber blades and could be more easily augmented**.
> - Also, their common usage by Sith and other Darksiders after this discovery caused synthetic crystals to become something of a staple among such groups, and their use among Jedi was strongly discouraged.
> - Most synthetic crystals were red, a result of the forging process, and oftentimes the initiate's intentional manipulations, as most individuals who utilized synthetic crystals were Darksiders.
> - The red-hued lightsaber blades generated by such crystals were often nicknamed "bloodshine blades". However, synth-crystals could be made in any color, requiring only slight adjustments of the creation process and special manipulations through the Force during the forging. **--Wookieepedia > [Synthetic lightsaber crystal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Synthetic_lightsaber_crystal)****

Comment: Nowadays long ago in a galaxy far far away.

Comment: There's also something to the notion that the colors were symbolic for some Force-wielders. Galen Marek said that his red Sith saber reminded him of fury and blood, whereas when he obtained a blue blade, it reminded him of the ocean and sky (he used his lightsaber as an aide to meditation).

Mace Windu's purple blade symbolized how he was able to use traditionally Dark Side fighting styles and techniques while remaining in control enough to make them serve the light side (red+blue=purple).

Comment: The symbolism of lightsaber colors - red for Sith, blue/green for Jedi -- is not so clear-cut in the Expanded Universe. Not only do Dark Jedi wield non-red lightsabers, but Jedi such as Adi Gallia (in the comics Star Wars: Republic) and Leia Organa Solo (in the Corellian Trilogy novels) wield red lightsabers. (About.com Sci-Fi/Fantasy)

Comment: It is just in case you can't spot the Sith by the other subtle clues - Black clothes, Black Hoods, Devil Horns, Monster Faces, Title "Darth", Evil Cackling Laughs, Heavy Stalker Breathing....

Comment: @Chris I always thought Leia used a yellow lightsaber

Comment: I wonder if there's WoG on the purple lightsaber. The [real story](http://screencrush.com/star-wars-samuel-l-jackson-purple-lightsaber/) is that Samuel L. Jackson asked for it so he could find himself in the fight scenes. Lucas initially refused, but later relented.

Answer (score 2):

Red lightsabers are made by the Sith by a process of making the kyber crystal bleed against its will which is torturing a crystal so to speak and can only be made to bleed by strong powers and emotions of hatred, anger, etc. So I'm sure Obi-Wan would not want to do that to his lightsaber.

I suggest you watch this video it should help: