# What explains the beam color of Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, rogue-one

In Rogue One there is a scene when Empire is plundering the Temple of the Kyber on Jedha.

From Rogue One dialogue:

> "What are they bringing in?"
>
> "It's what are they taking out. Kyber crystal... all they can get."

Sith use [synthetic crystals so their lightsabers are red.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22102/51085)

[But natural crystal has no color until the Jedi find it.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal)

**Given that Death Star uses Kyber crystals, what explains its beam color?**

Comment: It doesn't, it was green!

Comment: Fixed the color issue.

Comment: @janisz - Yes, but in doing so you've dramatically changed the meaning of the question **after answers were given**.

Comment: @Valorum - I fixed the question to have a more generic wording that is correct yet doesn't invalidate the answers.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - I'm happy if you're happy. Yours is the sole remaining (and thoroughly well researched) answer. Up voted and marked for reopening.

Comment: @Valorum - you know me, I'm always happy to fix a question to the point where it can be reopened and is well accepted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Synth kyber crystals are not Disney canon anymore

   https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/788187764936224768

   > @Apoc013 @KristianHarloff Natural. Synthetic kyber crystals is the stuff of legends.

   (Also see more details from "Ashoka" novel [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22101/why-do-the-sith-use-red-colored-lightsabers-but-the-jedi-dont?noredirect=1&lq=1))
2. **Death Star's beam wasn't red. It was *green*** (see screenshots below) in Rogue One.
3. That makes sense, in new canon, since red color was due to Sith "breaking" the crystal previously bonded to a Jedi.

   The crystals for Death Star were mined and taken directly by the Empire, not having undergone this process which is what caused the red color in Sith lightsabers:

   > Dark crystals were made, too, but not in that holy place. They were plundered from their rightful bearers and corrupted by the hands that stole them. Even rock could be changed by the power of the Force, bleeding alterations until their color was the deepest red. The balance was finely staged between the two, light and dark, and it took very little to upset it *(from above-linked answer quoting "Ashoka" book).*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there an explanation for the green color? I expected red just by association with Sith. Also the [wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kyber_crystal) talks about colorless crystals, until a jedi harnesses it > Crystals lacked color before they were chosen by a Jedi. Once chosen, most lightsabers became blue or green, though other shades were created in rare instances

Comment: Why was the Death Star beam *green*? (Rather than red, or clear.)

Answer (score 2):

In various episodes of *Star Wars: Rebels* and *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* we see some of the large kyber crystals that were being taken to build the Death Star laser. They aren't colourless, they're green.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**SWR: In the Name of the Rebellion**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/In_the_Name_of_the_Rebellion)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>[**SWTCW: Crystal Crisis**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Crystal_Crisis)</sup></sub>

[image]
<sub><sup>Clone Wars: Kyber Crystal Concept Art</sup></sub>