# What was the color of Dooku's lightsaber when he was a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

As [lightsabers are red because Sith use them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143240/931), the color of Dooku's lightsaber must not have been red when he was a Jedi. But, we also see that the color of a Jedi's lightsaber can vary: Yoda had a green lightsaber, the Jedi Temple Guards had yellow lightsabers, Windu had purple lightsaber, Ahsoka had a white lightsaber and blue lightsabers are the most famous among Jedi.

What color was Dooku's lightsaber when he was a Jedi?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

His second lightsaber as a Jedi was blue, we see this in *Age of Republic - Count Dooku* with a flashback where he is fighting Yoda as a demonstration.

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: I've checked both _Star Wars: The Complete Visual Dictionary_ and _Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know_ and whilst both mention Dooku's first lightsaber there is nothing beyond a mention of it.

Comment: At the rate the Jedi lost them, you'd think there'd be a decent secondary market...

Comment: @DavidW In this case at least he doesn't lose his first lightsaber. He just set it aside in favour of the new one he'd constructed as it was superior.

Comment: Which makes Jedi like my granddad who had drawers full of old tools he was never going to use again. :)

Comment: @DavidW - Anakin was (supposedly) forever tinkering with his lightsaber, adjusting the power settings and battery. I'm assuming Jedi are also capable of repairing anything that goes *sproing*

Comment: More importantly: is that a TIGER?!

Comment: @DavidW Apparently there is a secondary market - General Grievous in Ep. II was apparently a collector, despite being neither a Jedi nor a Sith as far as I'm aware.  And we know Maz Kanata had Luke's just lying around in a storage cellar for years.  So some people are clearly able to acquire them by other means.

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo Why not? If Wing Commander has the Kilrathi... :-)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Grievous didn't collect lightsabers from a market, but from Jedi he personally killed. https://general-grievous.fandom.com/wiki/Grievous%27s_Lightsaber_Collection

Comment: When Ahsoka loses one in Clone Wars, it is indeed sold on the black market.