# What species is this alien Jedi that looks like a tiger?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/243107/931) shows an alien Jedi(?) which looks like a [Bengal Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengal_tiger).

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

I have never seen such a species in the entire *Star Wars* franchise. Was it as rare as Yoda's?

What in-universe species is that Bengal Tiger?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently, that character is named [Jak'zin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jak%27zin), and he's a [Togorian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Togorian).

> Togorians were a sentient species of large, feline beings with back-jointed legs. Their bodies were covered in short fur that could be brown, white, or orange with black stripes, and their eyes could be yellow. They moved with grace and spoke with a sibilant voice. H'sishi, owner of the Yinchom Dojo, was a female Togorian. The male Jedi Knight Jak'zin, who encountered Count Dooku on Sullust, was a Togorian.

That specific image you posted is from *[Star Wars: Age of Republic - Count Dooku #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Age_of_Republic_-_Count_Dooku_Vol_1_1)*, published in 2019 and written by [Jody Houser](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jody_Houser). Here's the full page, where Jak'zin states his name:

[image]

Houser clarified Jak'zin's species in [a subsequent Tweet](https://twitter.com/Jody_Houser/status/1095758325197590528):

[image]

For the record, not all Togorians have that bengal tiger look. The first full appearance of a Togorian was in *[Star Wars: Thrawn #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Thrawn_Vol_1_3)* (also written by Houser), and the Togorian shown in that issue, [H'sishi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/H%27sishi), looked quite a bit different, though still distinctly feline:

[image]

Comment: Weird isn't it how speices that look like an Earth animal always have a name that sounds like that animal - Togorian, [Caitian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caitian)...

Comment: @DJClayworth [Maybe not so weird](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45842/2242), at least for Star Wars

Comment: _Jak'zin has wares, if you has coin._

Answer (score 9):

The Cathar were a species of feline, bipedal humanoids native to Cathar, a planet of savannas and rough uplands. They were known for their loyalty, passion, and temper. Quick and powerful, they were considered great warriors and dedicated, efficient predators.

The Cathar species had two subspecies, known as the Juhani and the Myr Rho. Both of these were notably less catlike than mainline Cathar.

Force-sensitive Cathar often became Jedi, even though the Jedi way tended to be in opposition to their natural tendencies.

Another Cathar Jedi of that era was Juhani, who traveled with Revan and assisted him in the destruction of the Star Forge. Famous Cathar Jedi during the Second Imperial Civil War were brothers Rasi, Ahn and Zho Tuum.

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cathar_(species)#