# Why are blue lightsabers most common among Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

Lightsabers of all Sith are red because [dark side makes crystals bleed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143240/931).

Is there something similar for Jedi? Although color of Jedi's lightsaber vary (Yoda had green lightsaber, Jedi Temple Guards had yellow lightsabers, Windu had purple lightsaber), blue lightsabers are most common.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1801/3804 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason that lightsabers have different colors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1779/what-is-the-reason-that-lightsabers-have-different-colors)

Comment: Windu had a purple saber